# Unable to retrieve docs in a specific folder in google docs using c#

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm trying to retrieve all documents in a folder in google docs using the below function as give in API documentation.. but still the function is returning the titles of all the documents and not only of that particular folder..

```
public DocumentsFeed RetrieveDocsInFolder(DocumentsService service, string folder, string email)
        {
            AtomCategory folderCategory = new AtomCategory(folder,
            new AtomUri("http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007/folders/" + email));
            QueryCategory folderQueryCategory = new QueryCategory(folderCategory);
            DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
            query.Categories.Add(folderQueryCategory);
            query.CategoryQueriesAsParameter = true;
            return service.Query(query);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public DocumentsFeed RetrieveDocsInFolder(DocumentsService service, string folder)
{
    string uri = String.Format(DocumentsListQuery.foldersUriTemplate, folder);
    DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery(uri);
    return service.Query(query);
}
```

I'm assuming `folder` is the resource ID of the folder you want to retrieve the content for.